# Images not aligning correctly

Tags: uploads, images

I am trying to upload new images to a website which was built by a developer[image]. I know my image sizes are wrong but what is the best way to ensure all images are the same size in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is implemented using image size feature what you want is so-called "hard crop" mode. That will make image fit dimensions *exactly*, possibly cutting of their parts.

What you seem to have is soft/proportional crop mode, which tries to fit image in *roughly* into dimensions, while preserving all of image.

See [crop mode in documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#crop-mode) for technical details.

If you want to get around this without messing with code, then your best option is to figure out target dimensions and upload images that have *exact* same ratio. That will make them fit existing setup, but is more work preparing them before upload.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems like your original image sizes are all different (*except for the last two*). For clean and consistent images, it's best to make sure they are all set to the appropriate size to fit before uploading them.

Otherwise, you can also use the built-in media tool to set the desired sizes to fit:

[image: Media editing tool]

Also, however your *product items* are displayed, It doesn't look like they automatically have a set `width` and `height` set to ensure all of the images follow the same dimensions. But that's just from looking at the screenshot and not the source code.